# Bar button item doesn't work when the app come from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to execute different code when i click the same bar button item. Every time when i click the background image change. I check which is this one and i select the code to be executed. That works, but when the app come from background the button doesnt work. Some ideas ?

This is the code is viewDidLoad:

```
[self.btnOnOff setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconON.png"]];
self.btnOnOff.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This is the method call when the user click

```
-(IBAction)btnOnOffAction:(id)sender
{
UIImage* selectedImgOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconOFF.png"];
UIImage* selectedImgON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconON.png"];

// UNAVAILABLE
if ([self.btnOnOff.image isEqual:selectedImgON])
{
    //  Ask user confirmation
    self.alertConfirmationStatus = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status of app"   message:@"Do you want to switch to UNAVAILABLE ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [self.alertConfirmationStatus show];
}

// AVAILABLE
else if ([self.btnOnOff.image isEqual:selectedImgOFF])
{
    //  Ask user confirmation
    self.alertConfirmationStatus = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status of app" message:@"Do you want to switch to \n AVAILABLE ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [self.alertConfirmationStatus show];
}

else {}
```

}

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to move your codes in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

or put some reference to your method.